# Whole Page Strikethrough with Variable length

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, strikeout, tabularray

Context:
I'm working on recreating the [AANZFTA CoO](https://www.abf.gov.au/free-trade-agreements/files/aanzfta-co-form.pdf) in LaTeX, which contains a list of varying length. I use longtblr to make it travel across multiple pages, and use a fancyfooter for the declaration at the bottom so that it's always flush with the bottom. The \textheight is set shorter so that the longtblr skips over to the next page early to avoid interfering with the footer. (I provide the context incase someone can think of a better solution than the one I'm thinking of)

Question:
On the final page, I need to have a Strike through the whole remainder of the table, from the bottom of the last item to the top of the footer.
Since the distance will change constantly, I need some sort of \vfill with a combined strike through from the top left to bottom right.

```
...
\end{tblr}
% Something here to cross out the rest of the document
\vfill{Strike?}
\end{document}
%footer will appear beneath this
```

[image: Desired Strikethrough outcome]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\textheight}{18cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6in}

\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text,contfoot-text, caption-text,caption-sep,caption-tag}{default}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|}, rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1} 
    \hline
    Header & Header \\
    \hline
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    \hline
    Footer & Footer \\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

% STRIKE THROUGH HERE

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pease provide a minimal and compilable example.

Comment: The remaining height is more or less equal to `\pagegoal-\pagetotal`.

Comment: Provided MWE now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "fancyfooter" in your code. But it is more or less like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\setlength{\textheight}{18cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.6in}

\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text,contfoot-text, caption-text,caption-sep,caption-tag}{default}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
   headsep = 0pt, footsep = 0pt, postsep = 0pt,   
]{colspec = {|X|X|}, rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1} 
    \hline
    Header & Header \\
    \hline
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    item.description & item.cost \\
    \hline
    Footer & Footer \\
    \hline
\end{longtblr}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{hline{2}, vlines, rowsep=0pt}
\diagbox[width=\textwidth-0.8pt,height=\pagegoal-\pagetotal-0.4pt]{}{}
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, that works well after some tinkering.
I also ran into the problem of not wanting the line to show up if the remaining space is too short, but I fixed that with the package `\etoolbox':
```\ifdimcomp{\pagegoal-\pagetotal}{>}{2cm}
    {
    \noindent
    \begin{tblr}{rowsep=0pt}
        \diagbox[width=\textwidth-0.8pt,height=\pagegoal-\pagetotal-0.4pt]{}{}
    \end{tblr}
}{}```

Cheers!